# How to apply a given directive value to multiple tags in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive, angular-template

I have recently started learning Angular and Material and in my project I realized, that I have to create forms with the same appearance. For instance the registration form's template looks like this:

```
<mat-card>
  <h2>{{'NAV.REGISTRATION' | translate}}</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="registrationForm" (ngSubmit)="submitRegistrationForm()">
    <div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput formControlName="fullName" placeholder="{{'REGISTRATION.NAME' | translate}} *">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput formControlName="password" placeholder="{{'REGISTRATION.PASSWORD' | translate}} *" type="password">
      </mat-form-field>
...
```

I would like to apply `appearance="outline"` to all the `<mat-form-field>` tags in the template. I have tried applying `<div class="mat-form-field-appearance-outline">`, but of course it causes the `<div>` element to appear with the styles, not its children. Also, I can not just simply write

```
mat-form-field{
  appearance: outline;
}
```

in the template's `.scss` file. So, in conclusion, in what ways can I apply a Material directive value to a custom set of tags without repeating it in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `MatFormFieldDefaultOptions` either on the module level (all fields in given module) or on a component level. It's covered in docs [here](https://v10.material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldDefaultOptions).

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uq2h5s) forked from their demo on form field that changes all the fields in the component.